# 1 kiloton nuclear device to clear up debris and dust to expose the iron-nickel core for open-pit mining (on M-Type asteroids)?

Tags: debris, asteroid, nuclear, mining, space-dust

My understanding is that initial acceleration from the blast and following solar wind will clear the area around the asteroid for spacecraft navigation (in reasonable time). A 2-3 kilometer [M-type asteroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-type_asteroid) (or smaller) would not have enough gravity to be able to keep around the dust cloud from the blast?

Comment: I understand that there are concerns regarding residual radiation left on the asteroid, but this is not a question here.

Comment: Every space faring nation has agreed to the [Outer Space Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty) and have agreed not to put weapons of mass destruction into space, so this is pretty much a non-starter.

Comment: @David Hammen - I don't think you can be that confident in this case. If NASA or other agency has not asked for research yet, it does not mean that this question will not be answered at some point. Do you have any other options on how to clear meters of dust and debris for open-pit mining operations on asteroids???

Comment: Opinion-based questions are not appreciated at this site, and at many other StackExchange network sites. "What do you think ..." is asking for opinions. Also, push questions ("Here's my analysis. Am I right or am I right???") questions also are not appreciated here. Finally, questions that are pure sci-fi are not appreciated here. I suggest you take your question to Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: @DavidHammen - I understand that talking about research subjects not covered in academic budgets creates some kind of irritation. But in many cases, science can look a little bit ahead of today's requirements. And if the question is not interesting to the community, it will be forgotten the next day.

Comment: I don't think we need to close this question for "primarily opinion-based answers" now that thoughtful and science-based answers have begun. Voting to **leave open**.

Comment: This question appears to imply that the non-core material isn't useful. That's probably not true. It can be a source of water, oxygen, construction materials, even reaction mass, as well as various interesting minerals.

Comment: Also, fission bombs are not a very efficient way of extracting energy from uranium / plutonium. Only a small percentage of the fuel undergoes fission before the bomb blows itself to bits. You'd get much more energy using it as fuel in a reactor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One kiloton moves both quite a lot and probably less than you need.

This study on [nuclear craters](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/6696719) along with a bunch of maths relevant to OPs interests has a table on page 24 summerising various actual blasts, including some subsurface low yield shots that got crater sizes around 100 feet and moved around 1 million cubic feet of material. While an asteroid will have lower density much lower gravity they provide a useful hard number to start with in terms of just turning blast into moved mass.

Moved into metric that is 28 thousand cubic meters, the table lists alluvial soil which is around 1.5 tonnes per cubic meter so 'moved' around 42,000 tonnes of material. It is notable that the table suggests smaller yields get more cubic volume moved per ton of yield.

Shifting 42k tonnes of material is great, but if we take [Bennu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101955_Bennu)  as an example asteroid that is still only 0.00006% of the total mass.

So we have moved thousands of tonnes of debris into the space around our target making it rather hazardous, but only moved a relatively small portion of the overall asteroid so not necessarily useful if trying to clear overburden off a metal core or trying to fully 'pit' the asteroid by ejecting the core entirely.

Separate to the questions around getting nuclear weapons for this purpose, a crater made this way will tend to expose frozen volitiles to sunlight which will probably tend to outgas long after the blast keeping the crater area populated with dust and debris, a more controlled mechanical excavation may reduce this, or even allow them to be captured.

There may be mining situations where this makes sense, but it is unclear at this time what that would be - if we are after [HE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3#Extraterrestrial) from the solar wind then we want to carefully strip the surface off without disturbing anything.

Comment: The report says near-surface is that above or below? I

Comment: "GremlinWranger" - Thank you for a thoughtful answer! It brings several points I was not thinking about.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 the report is interested in below surface level but given the limited data for actual detonations includes data for both. I based most of the answer on the Teapot ESS shot that was 1.2 Kt at -20 meters, which is also a useful data point on the machinery you'd need to place these. A 20+meter hole is not something you dig by hand even in zero g.

Answer (score 5):

While I'd have to check exactly what yield you would need you could probably expose the core of an asteroid fairly easily. However, you run into several massive issues.

1. the outer space treaty forbids the use of nukes in space
2. you would create a vast amount of space junk of a whole range of sizes. This space junk would spread out in all directions and make it increasingly risky to approach the asteroid. Additionally given the very large energies involved the space junk would fly out to a range of nearby orbits.
3. you've just made everything you want to mine fairly radioactive

Finally if you're wanting to mine the core of the asteroid then you're going to need mining equipment capable of cutting through whatever the core is made of. That means you already have the equipment to cut strait through the outer parts of the asteroid and reach the core, in which case why not simply do that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not a political forum, so I would not argue about chances to change the treaty if China were interested in this venture. Second, we are talking about the asteroid belt, not LEO. And collisions with a similar outcome (1 kiloton explosion) happen fairly often.

Comment: Starship SpaceX will have more than 2000 tons of fuel onboard. This is more than enough to bring several tons of equipment to an asteroid and start some exploratory work.

Comment: Morgan Stanley says that in 15-20 years private Space Industry will be 1 trillion dollars. So remarks about SCI-FI don't make much sense.  SpaceX evaluation already 130 billion dollars.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I'm not arguing politics I'm just saying that current laws forbid it. That being said it's often difficult to discuss space without politics as space programs are almost always government funded so it comes in along the way. Secondly Just because Morgan Stanley says something doesn't necessarily make it right or wrong. A lot of the future of space exploration depends on how successful starship is, the development of similar vehicles and various ISRU developments none of which are vaguely guaranteed. Basically everyone is usually guessing and trying to make headlines

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I'm not knowledgeable about the frequency of collisions in the asteroid belt, but space junk is always bad and you do not want to go making any more of it than you absolutely have to. Additionally, there is a big difference between two massive asteroids bumping into each other at low velocity, meaning most of the scattered material will also be low velocity, and be quickly recaptured, and nukes which will scatter space junk at high velocity, meaning it will both disrupt other orbits and be unlikely to be recaptured any time soon.

Comment: "Pioneer_11" - You bring valid points. But they are not making my question a non-starter. As asteroid mining will be inevitable in the future, as study on the possible use of nuclear devices will be inevitable as well.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I'm sure it will be studied but as I outlined there are major downsides to the use of nuclear weapons for asteroid mining without a compelling reason for them to be used. I simply do not see what problem they solve, if you want to expose the core you can do that by mining in with the equipment you brought to mine the core.

Comment: "Pioneer_11" - OK, now we are getting to the key problem. How to manage dust in near-zero gravity. NASA is conducting a big study on that for the Artemis mission. The equipment might not be able to function on an asteroid if you are constantly surrounded by abrasive dust from digging and explosions.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance you make several good points here that bolster the legitimacy and thoughtfulness of your question. It's just a suggestion, but in the future you might consider including some of this kind if thing from the beginning in your questions, to avoid the appearance of "Hey I just had a crazy idea, what if...?" that can attract reflexive down and close votes. While it's hard to add "prior research" to this question perhaps, at least add some "prior thinking-through" might help.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance Once answers start to appear, making substantial changes to a question is usually discouraged in Stack Exchange, and subsequent answer authors will often not pay attention to comments under other answers. So a bit of front-loading of questions can be helpful.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance that's a good point and dust is certainly going to be a big issue for space exploration. However, I'm struggling to conceive of a technology that would be incapable of digging down to the centre of the asteroid, yet simultaneously capable of mining it once it got there.

Comment: "Pioneer_11" - Great, we are on the point now. You can help me with my article :) What equipment would you bring to M-Type asteroid (platinum-rich) to dig through a solid iron-nickel core? It is like digging through the tank armor.

Comment: Just to remind, M-Type asteroids are similar in content to Earth's core and suspected to be the remnants of the core of a failed planet(s).

Comment: Sorry can you please clarify? Are you going after platinum in the asteroid? You don't make any mention of platinum in the question so I assumed you were after the iron/nickel in the core itself.

Comment: Also do you have any information on how the platinum is distributed in the asteroid and/or how firmly the iron/nickel is held together? I know M types are similar in content to earth's core and undergo differentiation so I'd assume you would find most platinum in the central core but I assume it's still not a single nugget.

Comment: "Pioneer_11" - Sorry, last time I mentioned platinum on this forum, they closed my question :). So I will try to avoid 'money talk' here and in my article :)

Comment: I think you meant to post a link but I'm not seeing anything on my end

Comment: "Pioneer_11" - they expect to find 80% of iron, around 15% of nickel and 0.5% of rare heavy metals. But nobody knows yet, of course.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance without a clear idea of the distribution of platinum within the asteroid and/or how the material in the asteroid is bound together I can't really contribute anything more than I already have. If you can find me a paper on the subject I'll be happy to have a look or I will have a look myself when I have some more time. That being said, to get the platinum out you're going to have to cut it, and whatever else it's mixed up with, free from the rest of the core. The machinery you use to do that will probably be suitable for getting there in the first place.